# Copying format settings from one stream to another

Tags: c++, stream, formatting

I'm writing a print method for my class, like:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const MyClass& M);
```

Inside I need to create an intermediate `stringstream`, so that I later put the string I got to the correct position in the `stream`. But `stream` could have some non-default settings like precision, field width, number format, etc..

How to copy all such formatting settings from `stream` to my `stringstream`, without manual doing "read-and-set" for each setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use **[copyfmt()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/copyfmt/)** to copy format options from one stream to the other:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const MyClass& M) {
    std::ostringstream tmp;     // temporary string stream
    tmp.copyfmt(stream);        // COPY FORMAT of origninal stream
    ...                         // rest of your code
    }
```

All formatting options is copied at once, for example :

```
MyClass o; 
...
std::cout.fill('*');
std::cout.width(10);
std::cout << o<<std::endl;    // stringstream rendering would use fill and width here 
std::cout << std::hex << o << std::dec <<std::endl;  // and even hex conversion here
```